# Appcelerator Angular Routing iOS - How to run sample application?

Tags: ios, angular, appcelerator

I've tried running this application:

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium-angular

Command-line call to run iOS app (appc run -p ios) fails with this output:

```
[INFO]  Launching iOS Simulator
-- Start simulator log ----------------------------------------------- 
--------
[INFO]  AngularDemo/1.0.0 (6.3.0.3620088)
[ERROR] Script Error {
[ERROR]     column = 35;
[ERROR]     line = 30;
[ERROR]     message = "Can't find variable: Symbol";
```

Can anyone help me run this iOS application?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us help you better, please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the SDK version 7.5.1.GA and set it on the tiapp.xml. You are using old CLI. Try updating by appc setup. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, That was the answer!

Comment: You are welcome. You can rate the answer if you like.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. I tried to rate your answer up! Thanks!